# Why the colors in pic 1 are so vibrant?

Tags: texturing, color

In the pic 1 the colors look very fresh and vibrant but in 2nd they look dull. What's the difference between the two and how can I turn colors from pic 2 to pic 1?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try going to _Render Properties_ > _Color Management_, and changing _View Transform_ from _Filmic_ to _Standard_

Comment: At least some of this effect may be due to [color constancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_constancy)  .. (search other links, for more dramatic examples.) I suspect if you desaturated the background sky, in the second example, the foreground colors would become more vibrant.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett that works a bit. Thanks!